# Sampling one record per unique value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a large dataframe containing users and their data. Each user can have multiple rows. I want to sample 1-row per user.
My current solution seems inefficient:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user2', 'user3'],
                 'B': ['B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4','B5'],
                 'C': ['C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4','C5'],
                 'D': ['D', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3','D4','D5'],
                 'E': ['E', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3','E4','E5']},
                 index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5]

userList = list(df1.User.unique())

usersSample = pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe, to save samples
for i in userList:
    usersSample=usersSample.append(df1[df1.User == i].sample(1)) 

> usersSample   
B   C   D   E   User
0   B   C   D   E   user1
4   B4  C4  D4  E4  user2
3   B3  C3  D3  E3  user3
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
df1.groupby('User').apply(lambda df: df.sample(1))
```

[image]

Without the extra index:

```
df1.groupby('User', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.sample(1))
```

[image]

Comment: We could do `lambda df: df.head(1)` to get the first value, in case order is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Based on number of rows per user this might be faster:

```
df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates(['User'])
```

Comment: This is quicker on `df1`.  Slower on `pd.concat([df for _ in range(100000)])`

Comment: @piRSquared I tried it on a larger dataset but User column's type was integer (117ms vs 3.96s) but it seems when the type is object it is always slower.

Comment: @piRSquared Ah sorry, the difference comes from the number of users. The number of users is quite small in this example.

Comment: `df= pd.DataFrame('user' + pd.Series(np.random.choice(range(1000), (1000000))).astype(str), columns=['User'])`  358 ms for you, 4.22 s for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1_user_sample_one = df1.groupby('User').apply(lambda x:x.sample(1))
```

Using DataFrame.groupby.apply and lambda function to sample 1

Answer (score 0):

`.drop_duplicates` should work just fine:

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset='User')
```

This will keep each first occurrence of a value in the column 'User' and return the respective row.

Comment: _This will keep each first occurrence of a value_ Isn't the question about a sample?